# I need to write the code for size based bucketting in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

my model data is like

{
   sensor_id: 12345,
   timestamp: ISODate("2019-01-31T10:00:00.000Z"),
   temperature: 40
}

{
   sensor_id: 12345,
   timestamp: ISODate("2019-01-31T10:01:00.000Z"),
   temperature: 40
}

{
   sensor_id: 12345,
   timestamp: ISODate("2019-01-31T10:02:00.000Z"),
   temperature: 41
}

and expected output is like:

{

```
sensor_id: 12345,

start_date: ISODate("2019-01-31T10:00:00.000Z"),

end_date: ISODate("2019-01-31T10:59:59.000Z"),
measurements: [
   {
   timestamp: ISODate("2019-01-31T10:00:00.000Z"),
   temperature: 40
   },
   {
   timestamp: ISODate("2019-01-31T10:01:00.000Z"),
   temperature: 40
   },
   … 
   {
   timestamp: ISODate("2019-01-31T10:42:00.000Z"),
   temperature: 42
   }
],
```

transaction_count: 42,
   sum_temperature: 2413
}

I have some different data set but actual problem is to use $facet with giving the start time and end time for size based bucketting in  mongodb.

Comment: or refer to this link https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern but it didnt contains solution.